# Prove that if $n\in\Bbb{N}$ is odd, and $\phi(n)$ is a power of 2,then $n$ is a product of distinct primes.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that if $n\in\Bbb{N}$ is odd, and $\phi(n)$ is a power of 2,then $n$ is a product of distinct primes. 
I didn't really think I understood this question. What is the condition exactly? That in the prime factorization there has to be more than one prime? For $n=17$, $\phi(n)=16=2^4$ and 17 is odd. What is for the prime factorization? Is this factorization in sync with the criteria? I could really use some help here.

Comment: It means $n$ is squarefree. No square of a prime divides $n$.

Comment: A product of distinct primes means a product of primes no prime of which is repeated (repetition occurs if an prime has an exponent $\ge2$ in the prime factorization). For instance, $12=2\cdot2\cdot3$ is not a product of distinct primes, because the first two factors in the product are both the same prime.

Comment: I thought it might be an option. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition says that $\;\varphi(n)=2^r\;,\;\;r\in\Bbb N\;$ , and what's to be proved is that $\;n\;$ is a product oof **different** odd primes (unlike $\;45=3^2\cdot5\;,\;\;75=3\cdot5^2\;$ , etc. , and like $\;21=3\cdot7\;,\;\;105=3\cdot5\cdot7\;$ , etc.)

Let $\;p_1,...,p_k\;$ be odd primes, and supose

$$n=p_1^{a_1}\cdot\ldots\cdotp_k^{a_k}\implies \varphi(n)=n\prod_{i=1}^k\left(1-\frac1{p_i}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{a_i-1}\left(p_i-1\right)$$

Since $\;\varphi(n)\;$ is a power of $\;2\;$ , it *must be* that $\;a_i=1\;\;\forall\,i\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

It means that $n$ can be written as:
$$n = p_1p_2\dots p_k$$
With all of the $p_1,\dots,p_k$ different primes.

Now for your question, let $n$ be an odd number such that $\phi(n)$ is a power of two. Let's write $n$  as a product of prime factors:
$$n = p_1^{a_1} \dots p_k^{a_k}$$
with $p_1,\dots,p_k$ different primes and $a_1,\dots,a_k \in \mathbb{N}$.
If we prove that $a_i=1$ for all $i = 1,\dots k$, then we are done.(Why?)

Now it is well known (and easy to prove) that 
$$\phi(n)= (p_1-1)p_1^{a_1}\dots(p_k-1)p_k^{a_k-1}$$
We are given that this number is a power of two, so every factor must be a power of two. Because $n$ is odd, every prime $p_i$ is different from $2$. Suppose now there is a prime $p_i$ with $a_i >1$, then this would imply that $p_i^{a_i-1}$ is a power of two, hence $p_i$ should be $2$. This is a contradiction.

Please tell me if I have to elaborate at some points in my argument.